# Can I use formvalidation.io with React and Materialize-css

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, materialize, formvalidation.io

Is it possible to use [formvalidation.io](https://formvalidation.io) plugin along with React and [Materialize-css](https://materializecss.com/).

My project has multiple `input components` which may or may not be used inside a `form`. I would like to use `formvalidation` plugin for validation of input component.

Not able to find any documentation related to this. **Is this possible?** If possible please someone share me references related to this.

#### Updates:

1. I found there this [documentation](https://formvalidation.io/updates/v1.0.0/#new-features) in form validation plugin website,
   where its clearly mentioned that how to use form validation in
   React. But not able to find any detailed documentation related to
   this.
2. This is how right now I tried to import jQuery and
   formvalidation plugin into my project, but when I am loading
   formvalidation getting error saying, formvalidation require jquery.

```js
import $ from "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
window.M = M;
import "formvalidation/dist/js/formValidation.min.js"
```

Thanks for all feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found some documentation related to this with help of Formvalidation.io team.

This documentation explains how to use form-validation in materialize css : [Reference - Using formvalidation with materialize css](https://formvalidation.io/updates/)

This documentation give information about how to use formvalidation in React : 
[Reference - Using formvalidation with react](https://formvalidation.io/guide/api/)